# Docker container not updating media folder from AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3

I'm having trouble getting a docker container to update the images (like .png's) on my local system.

The docker container has script in the dockerfile that copies the images into a folder in the container. Then, that folder gets copied into a new directory that is a set up as a shared volume. This process is split between the dockerfile for this container, and a "command" entry in the docker-compose.yaml.

Everything *seems* to run fine; following the output of the copy command looks right. I don't get any errors, and once the command stops running the container stops.

I've tried destroying the container and image completely and recreating it, but I still see the old images in the application. I'm guessing that it's not overwriting the existing images, but I don't know why.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Install packages
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils
RUN apt-get install -y curl unzip

# Intall AWS CLI
RUN curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
RUN unzip awscliv2.zip
RUN ./aws/install

# Load AWS Access Keys
COPY ./config /root/.aws/
COPY ./credentials /root/.aws/
RUN chmod 600 /root/.aws/config /root/.aws/credentials

# Download media
RUN mkdir -p /var/media
RUN aws s3 cp --recursive s3://images/ /var/media
```

Snippet from the docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
    client:
        [[other stuff here]]

    media:
        image: [[our own image stored with AWS]]
        command: 'cp -R -v -f /var/media/images/ /var/media-access/'
        volumes:
            - ./src/media:/var/media-access

[[other stuff here]]
```

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Anyone who gets a copy of this image can `docker run --rm the-image cat /root/.aws/credentials` and get your credentials out; you almost certainly don't want that.  If you have valid AWS credentials at this point anyways, can you run `aws s3 cp` without involving Docker?  Or set up your application to either serve up externally-visible S3 URLs or proxy S3, without actually having a local copy of the content?

Comment: The goal was to automate this process. The images update every once in a while and we wanted them to update easily without the developers needing to do it manually. There are some images that are created when the app is run locally, so we don't want developers stepping over each other. 

Thanks for the heads up about the credentials. We have IAM profiles for these so the damage anyone can do with the creds that these containers use is minimal, and easily disabled

Comment: Are you building the image with `--no-cache=true` to prevent the `aws s3 sync` command layer from being cached?

Comment: They guy that set this up created the images, so I have no clue. Is there a way to check this?